# calling function inside angular factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory, how do i call 'getAccountDetails' service inside getAccountInformation() function.

I tried in the following way, but not working.

```
AccountService.getAccountDetails.getAccountDetailsService
```

### factory

```
tellerApp.factory('AccountService',['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return{
        getAccountDetails: $resource(XXX, {}, {
            getAccountDetailsService: {}
        }),
        getAccountInformation: function($scope, number, transaction, index){
            AccountService.getAccountDetails.getAccountDetailsService({number : number})
           .$promise.then(function(response){});       
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you define your code dependencies out of the returned provider:

```
tellerApp.factory('AccountService',['$resource', function ($resource) {

    var getAccountDetails = $resource(XXX, {}, {getAccountDetailsService: {}});

    return {
        getAccountDetails : getAccountDetails,
        getAccountInformation: function($scope, number, transaction, index){
            getAccountDetails.getAccountDetailsService({number : number}).$promise.then(function(response){
                 ...
            })
        }      
    };
}]);
```

Or, inside an object, you can also use `this` to refer to the current object, instead of using `AccountService.getAccountDetails`, you should use `this.getAccountDetails`.

```
tellerApp.factory('AccountService',['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return {
        getAccountDetails : $resource(XXX, {}, {getAccountDetailsService: {}});,
        getAccountInformation: function($scope, number, transaction, index){
            this.getAccountDetails.getAccountDetailsService({number : number}).$promise.then(function(response){
                 ...
            })
        }      
    };
}]);
```

Plus, be careful, because your naming convention is confusing (`getAccountDetails` is not a function, since you don't call it with `()`, but it is named "get", `getAccountServices` is first defined as an object, but the same name is used later for a funtion...), especially if you want an accurate answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, havent tested it though.

```
tellerApp.factory('AccountService',['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var AccountService = {
        getAccountDetails: $resource(XXX, {}, {
            getAccountDetailsService: {}
        }),
        getAccountInformation: function($scope, number, transaction, index){
            AccountService.getAccountDetails.getAccountDetailsService({number : number}).$promise.then(function(response){
            }
        };       

    }
    return AccountService
}]);
```